# Multi-Language Website with RESX Files

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, dnx

I've been looking around for an example on how to use RESX files for localization on MVC6 and so far I was not able to find a good example.

My website will have a dropdown list with all the avalible languages. I dont want the application to automatically detect localization. My ideia would be for the user to select a language and then a view would select the appropriate language (maybe keep the language as a Cookie) from my RESX folder.

So far I've created a folder with my Resources.resx, Resources.en-EN.resx, Resources.es-ES.resx.

Does anyone have a good working example for this? Thank you very much!